# corresponding mean of 3d array in python

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing, 3d, mean

let x = random.rand(100, size =(P, r, c),
where P =pages, r= rows and c= columns
I want to calculate the mean of array of size =(P, r, c) having output in size= (r, c).
simply I am converting 3D array in 2D array by calculating mean of every index on different pages.

Comment: `x.mean(axis=0)`? This has got to be a duplicate many times over.